# How to insert shopping cart data into MySQL database using JQuery, Backbone and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, backbone.js

I found the code here but it does not provide insert into database 
http://www.spicevanjava.nl/tech-talk/shopping-cart-ui-demo-mobile-version/

here the example
index.html

```
<script type="text/template" id="submit-btn-tmpl">
    <button data-icon="arrow-d" data-theme="b" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</script>
```

shopping-cart.js

```
// Submit Button
var SubmitButton = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.basket-footer',

    //get template
    template:  $('#submit-btn-tmpl').template(),

    appRouter: null,

    initialize: function() {
        // set appRouter
        this.appRouter = this.options.appRouter;
    },

    render : function () {

        var totalPrice = 0

        // get total price
        if (this.appRouter.basketItems.length > 0)
            totalPrice = this.appRouter.basketItems.totalPrice();

        // clean up
        $('#submit-btn').remove();

        // and finally render this view with total price
        $(this.el).append($.tmpl(this.template, {price:totalPrice}));
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not a jQuery mobile question. Consider retagging this.

Comment: @passionateCoder may I not what exactly the language?It also use JSON..

Comment: The tags must read jquery, backbone.js, php, mysql :-)

Comment: @passionateCoder thank you very much T.T..but do you know how to solve my problem?